# run program as administrator from privileged .bat script

Tags: batch-file

i have the following script

```
NET SESSION >nul 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 ( ECHO Administrator PRIVILEGES Detected! ) ELSE ( ECHO NOT AN ADMIN!)
set keyFolder=C:\downloads
set keyWeb=http://localhost:9802/blabla/file.txt
rem net start somePool
ping %keyWeb%
set scriptDir=%~dp0
%scriptDir:~0,2%
cd %scriptDir%
ping %keyWeb%
getWEb.exe "%keyWeb%" "%keyFold%\auth_public_key.txt"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 ( ECHO good, it was downloaded! ) ELSE ( ECHO bad, not downloaded!)
```

this script runs as administrator being called by a periodinc program 
unfortunately

```
getWEb.exe "%keyWeb%" "%keyFold%\auth_public_key.txt"
```

sometimes runs without administrator privilege 
i tried other methods, unfortunately i can not use runas /profile with username+password because the machine is not allowed and passwords are valid only when we connect to the machine via rdp

Comment: ps: if right click the .bat "run as administrator" then getweb.exe works fine

Answer (score 0):

Make a shortcut to your bat file.
Right-click your shortcut and choose
properties - shortcut -advanced - run as administrator